# Turn off notifications under Scientific-linux 6.1

Tags: gnome, scientific-linux, notifications

Besides:

```
chmod -x /usr/libexec/notification-daemon
reboot
```

are there any solutions to turn off permanently all the annoying notification messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer: as SL uses GNOME, [this tells you the `gconf` keys for disabling at least the power management's notifcations](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/stable/notify.html.en).  So in case these are your "annoying" ones...

**Edit** another part, I think you're done with notifications if you [disable the *Notification Area Applet*](http://playingwithsid.blogspot.com/2008/10/gnome-notification-area-applet.html), probably via some GUI panel options.